# Forms CSS ... this is getting ridiculous

Tags: css, forms

**Bottom Line Up Front**

Is there a CSS way to solve this?
Or will I have to hack this jquery plugin I'm using to move the dynamic dropdown div to the OUTSIDE of the form, do a position:absolute, and move it back up in the form?

(hmmm this 'tags' field at stackoverflow looks like JUST what I need :-)

***EDIT*** Fixed page example to validate. Sorry, should have done this before submitting question.

***EDIT*** 20 July: removing fieldset CSS for z-index:0 solves it for FireFox. I tested out http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/ -- which appends the DIV to the end of the html BODY, which works cross browser.

**Background**

Simple form with a couple fieldsets w/legends. CSS is nothing fancy:

```
label { float:left; width: 150px; }
input { float: left; width: 132px; }
fieldset { position:relative; }
```

**Note** *that means, in the HTML, I do a BR-tag w/a clear:left after each input tag.*

--> The form looks nice, alls is well.

**Driving goal**

But, 1 field in the middle has WAY too much data (i.e., all the main US patent classifications codes). Therefore, this needs to be a LOT more usable. I'm thinking ... autocomplete ... save matches, so a text field that "tokenizes" the matches ... etc.

Perfect, this is a common enough need. So, I slap on a jquery plugin for a tokenizing, multiselecting, text-field plugin. There are only a few that do multiple selects, with autocomplete. Pick any one of them. I've tried them all :-)

All tend to do a $(input).insertAfter() of some HTML snippet -- typically a  which gets filled via Javascript to contain a UI/LI list.

--> Still good, no wackiness yet.

**Problem**

Oh my god -- legends, fieldsets, checkboxes, EVERYTHING weaves itself in & over top the dropdown div/ul contents. This is *NOT* an IE z-index problem.

- position:absolute mashes this up and won't drop nicely like a nav menu, tooltip, css popup or such typically does
- position:relative stops it mashing up, but ... well ... its relative now. So, the container fieldset stretches down, etc.
- firebug, mucking with z-index/position, etc on the CSS just won't solve this.

Do I have to hack the plugin to insert the DIV dropdown snippet outside of the form?
(then position:absolute;z-index:999; top/left move up back into the form)
Or ... is there a CSS solution?

**References:**

- **Screenshot** (with highlighting CSS) of the CRUNCH mixed legend, checkboxes, fieldset and drop-down div at 
  http://www.flickr.com/photos/turnerscraft/3733488100/
- **Jquery Tokenizing AutoComplete Text plugin**
  http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/
- **Relative Positioning** can work, but thats not a
  solution. See http://test.iplookout.com/search/

Comment: Could you please provide a link similar to the "relative positioning link" where you have the not properly working version? Probably OneNerd gave the right answer. But only with the screenshot it is hard to say.

Comment: The posted link (http://test.iplookout.com/search/) is the position:relative that works.

It works, but only because it avoids the problem -- not solves it.

In the field "US Classification(s)", type in some classification choices (mineral, min, mus, apparatus, app) -- div doesn't lay over the other field elements.  It pushes them down.

This is the best I can do with only altering the CSS of this plugin.

Comment: http://test.iplookout.com/search/ is now position:absolute with valid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OK -- I found the answer.**

There is **no** pure-CSS solution (that I could find) that allows the existing jquery plugin's drop-down list to properly hover over all form elements.

**Lesson learned**: if they haven't crafted the markup properly ... there is nothing you can do.

Here is what I did to fix the Tokenizing Autocomplet Text Entry plugin (jquery)
from http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/

Edit the jquery.tokeninput.js file to:

1. Alter how it initially inserts the DIV

   - Find the place where the dropdown is created (var dropdown = ...)
   - Replace its .insertAfter(token_list) with .appendTo(document.body)
   - This ensures the markup is not in the normal form/html flow
   - Do this where the code initializes and inserts the dynamic "" its going to use
2. Alter its location when it shows the DIV

   - Need to make sure it places the div **not** at the bottom, but under the input field
   - So, in the show_dropdown_searching() function, tack these onto the string of calls tacked on the dropdown var (see below). Do this just before the .show() call.

.

```
.css("position", "absolute")
.css("top", $(token_list).offset().top + $(token_list).height()) 
.css("left", $(token_list).offset().left)
```

Answer (score 5):

You didn't actually mention this in your question, but you're only experiencing the problem in IE, right? Because I can't reproduce it in any other browser.

The answer is pretty simple:

**Fix your doctype!**

Your current doctype triggers [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) because it's missing the system identifier. Consequently, all bets are off. Change it to HTML4 Strict:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Even fixing your current doctype should do:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Or better yet, use the HTML5 doctype (since the only thing doctypes are good for is triggering standards mode, and this is the shortest doctype you need to do so):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of IE are you using? This is a known problem in IE6.

In IE6, selects are [windowed objects](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177378) which means they exist on a plane above all other windowless elements on a page. The Select element in IE6 does not support [z-index and other properties](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/01/17/514076.aspx).

The only way I have reliably gotten around this problem is to hide the select with 'display:none' when the select is covered by the other element.

---

edit after comment

Removing z-index:0 from `form#newsearch div.fs, form#newsearch fieldset` in base_new.css (line 251) will fix it in FF

Comment: I was just reading about Windowed vs. Non-Windowed elements last night. I will try an IFRAME solution to see -- HOWEVER, it occurs with Firefox 3.0.5,  Chrome, Safari and IE.  --> hence the post to StackOverflow :-)

Comment: Ah...I thought you were just having an IE problem. See my edit for a fix. It still won't work in IE6 though.

Comment: ****   Yes -- for firefox, the removal of fieldset{z-index:0} solved the problem.  The drop-down div now lies on top of the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a `z-index` issue. Try to increase the `z-index` of the div showed for the autocomplete.

Comment: please, please read my posting.
I've added "position:relative;z-index:1" (0, 1, 99999, and all other index values that are large). And I've tried position:absolute

I've added "position:relative;z-index:0" (and -1, oops) to the other field elements.

All to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot to follow, but wondering if you tried placing the item inside of a <div> tag, then you can assign style info to the div (like height and overflow)?

**Upon further inspection** of your screen shot -- is that a div that appears with the possible items -- is that what the issue is? It's not appearing above the other form elements? I am not sure I understand exactly, but based on screen shot, looks like you may be able to either adjust the zindex, or the transparency of that div make it fully opaque).

Comment: Yes

Core issue = the div does not lay on top of the other form elements: fieldset, legend, checkbox, label, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of interest put have you tried using the clear:both CSS tag after the floats to see if this has any effect? E.g. `<br style="clear:both" />`.

Comment: In between the form "rows" (label, input pairs) I do a <br class="clear">.

In the styles for the plugin ... I've not tried that, since there is only the "dropdown div" and the inside "ul li tags" -- and they all line up nicely.